# Tracing using addresses obtained from execinfo.h to human readable format

Tags: c++, linux

I want to trace some addresses I received from a trace file (execinfo.h / backtrace) (see below) back into humand readable function calls.

From the backtrace I got:

Obtained 10 stack frames.

> /app/name() [0x81e4912]
>
> /app/name() [0x81e4332]
>
> [0xffffe40c]
>
> /app/name() [0x81ddb32]
>
> /app/name() [0x81f6a54]
>
> /app/name() [0x81e2576]
>
> /app/name() [0x81e2386]
>
> /app/name() [0x81f795b]

I want to translate the above lines into more readable form like this:

> functioncall1() line x
>
> functioncall2() line x
>
> SigFault() line x <- here I called the backtrace and write it to
> output stream

I got the corresponding .bin .hex files etc. I could go normally through all the addresses and look for the classes but this wont help me for my problem. Is there a sys command for me doing that automatically? I have looked into the execinfo.h dokumentation but I dont find something about my problem.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? Also, it requires debug symbols so code can even be mapped to source lines.

Comment: It should be used to get information after a crash not during development. Basically I catch signals and then generate the trace. Now I need to reinterprete the trace to follow the function calls in order to find the root cause. @UlrichEckhardt

Answer (score 0):

addr2line has done the job for me

```
for i in `grep "\[0x.*\]" $Filename |sed -e "s/.*\[\|\].*$//g"`;
  do
    echo $i
    mem_start="$(( $i ))"
    mem_end="$(( $i + 1 ))"
    **addr2line -e ${BINARY} $i**
    objdump ${BINARY} --start=$mem_start --stop=$mem_end -S 
  done
done
```